# How to change a UNION to a IN clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I need to get a maximum of 3 distinct records from the same table, so currently I'm doing:

```
SELECT 1, mycolumn FROM mytable WHERE id = @firstId
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, mycolumn FROM mytable WHERE id = @secondId
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, mycolumn FROM mytable WHERE id = @thirdId
```

The actual `SELECT` part contains over 20 columns and the `FROM` part contains a number of `JOINs`. The first column is a constant and is always fixed depending on the record. I don't know how many records might return. It could be anything from 0 to 3 records.

Is it possible to change the above query so that it uses `IN` like this:

```
SELECT ???, mycolumn FROM mytable WHERE id IN (@firstId, @secondId, @thirdId)
```

But how do I explicitly map each record to the fixed constant if I use `IN`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use a `CASE` expression here with a single query:

```
SELECT
    CASE id WHEN @firstId  THEN 1
            WHEN @secondId THEN 2
            WHEN @thirdId  THEN 3 END AS val,
    mycolumn
FROM mytable
WHERE
    id IN (@firstId, @secondId, @thirdId);
```

If you wish to also order by the computed column, then add `ORDER BY val` to the end of the above query.

Comment: `ORDER BY val` to make sure the result will be the same than the original query, or it's not needed (`@firstId, @secondId, @thirdId` are not necessary in ascending order)?

Comment: @Cid The OP's original query does not have an outer `order by`, so it can return rows as 3,1,2 too.

Comment: @Cid Good point, but the OP does not actually order.  The OP may add an `ORDER BY` clause if he wishes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `CASE` like following.

```
SELECT 
       CASE 
              WHEN id= @firstId THEN 1 
              WHEN id=@secondId THEN 2 
              ELSE 3 
       END AS rn, 
       mycolumn 
FROM   mytable 
WHERE  id IN (@firstId, 
              @secondId, 
              @thirdId)
```

Another approach can be using `DENSE_RANK` if you have one record for each provided id and @firstId, @secondId & @thirdId are in ascending order.

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() 
         OVER( 
           ORDER BY id) rn, 
       mycolumn 
FROM   mytable 
WHERE  id IN ( @firstId, @secondId, @thirdId )
```

Comment: `Same thing` - no, they're different. The second one will have gaps in the numbering like in the OP's example, the first one will not. I assume the OP is using these numbers to identify by which of the `in` parameters the record was found.

Comment: I like your `CASE` approach, but the first approach might not work if the `id` does not sort in a certain way +1.

Comment: Would the `Row_number` query match the rows? For example, if I only have records for `@firstId` and `thirdId`, the constant column must 1 and 3.

Comment: @PSK Still wrong. It needs to have gaps if some rows are missing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, thanks, I have updated the description accordingly

Comment: @GSerg, i have changed the row_number to dense_rank. It should now match the description provided. Thanks

Comment: @PSK `dense_rank` will not produce gaps either.

Comment: @PSK . . . The second version assumes that the ids are ordered, which is not stated in the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I agree, I just gave a alternate approach, but I mentioned in the answer that it should be in ordered form.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a table-valued constructor for this purpose:

```
select v.outputnum, my_column
from mytable t join
     (values (@firstid, 1),
             (@secondid, 2),
             (@thirdid, 3)
     ) v(id, outputnum)
     on t.id = v.id
order by v.outputnum;
```

I think this is simpler than other versions, because the list of ids is only present once in the query -- so no danger of different parts of the query getting out of sync.

Comment: This is for sure the best solution. +1